# ¿Cómo tomar todos los valores de un forearch para insertar en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Mi código

```
public function editar_clave($incial,$final,$clave_bien,$ano){
    //echo $id_tarjeta.'<br>';
    echo $incial.'<br>';
    echo $final.'<br>';
    echo $clave_bien.'<br>';
    echo $ano.'<br>';

    foreach (range($incial,$final) as $numero) {
        $numero_inventario=str_pad($numero, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $sql="INSERT INTO inventario (clave_bien,numero_inventario,ano) VALUES 
('$clave_bien', '$numero_inventario', $ano)";
       return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }
 }
```

Se supone que debería hacer los *insert* de acuerdo al rango que se da, por ejemplo del 1 al 2

- claveBien-0000001/2022
- claveBien-0000002/2022

Esos datos deberían de ser insertados en una tabla en la base de datos, pero solo toma el primer valor a insertar

- claveBien-0000001/2022

E ignora los de más, es decir, que si el rango fuera del 1 al 10 solo inserta el primero y los de mas no.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas haciendo un `return` donde no debes. En otras palabras estas indicando que el resultado devuelto es simplemente la ejecución de la función `ejecutarConsulta` una sola vez. Intenta esto (sin el `return`)

```
foreach (range($incial,$final) as $numero) {
       $numero_inventario=str_pad($numero, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
          $sql="INSERT INTO inventario (clave_bien,numero_inventario,ano) VALUES 
('$clave_bien', '$numero_inventario', $ano)";
       ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Csharls muchas gracias, en efecto es por eso